# returning tuple of list of lists of complex from c++ to python

Tags: c++, python-3.x, ctypes

I have a `PyObject* outvar` object which is basically constructed as:

```
//some defs
typedef std::complex<double> Pt;
typedef std::vector<Pt> Pgon;
typedef std::vector<Pgon> Pgons;
PyObject* outvar = PyTuple_New(2);

auto outA = pgons2pylist(pA);
auto outB = pgons2pylist(pB);
PyTuple_SET_ITEM(outvar, 0, outp);
PyTuple_SET_ITEM(outvar, 1, outl);
```

where `pgons2pylist`

```
PyObject* pgons2pylist(const Pgons& data) {
  PyObject* listObj = PyList_New( data.size() );
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        PyList_SET_ITEM(listObj, i, pgon2pylist(data[i]));
    }
    return listObj;
}
```

and `pgon2pylist` is:

```
PyObject* pgon2pylist(const Pgon& data) {
  PyObject* listObj = PyList_New( data.size() );
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        PyList_SET_ITEM(listObj, i, PyComplex_FromDoubles(data[i].real(),data[i].imag()));
    }
    return listObj;
}
```

I compile it and run it from `py` file as:

```
mylib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./mylib.so')
out_data = mylib.call(some_args)
```

but `out_data` is always an integer! how can I converted to [[complex]]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you structured your *C* code, looks closer to an *extension module* ([[Python 3]: Extending Python with C or C++](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html)) rather than a simple *.dll*. Check [[SO]: Pass str as an int array to a Python C extended function (extended using SWIG) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47276327/pass-str-as-an-int-array-to-a-python-c-extended-function-extended-using-swig/47296602#47296602) for a comparison between methods.

Then, as a note you need to specify *argtypes* and *restype* for an imported function (this is the exact reason why you get an *int*). Check [[SO]: Python ctypes cdll.LoadLibrary, instantiate an object, execute its method, private variable address truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52268294/python-ctypes-cdll-loadlibrary-instantiate-an-object-execute-its-method-priva) for what might happen if you don't.

Also listing [[Python 3]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) page.

Couple of notes about the code:

- Since you use *Python C API* functions in your *.dll*, you should call it via `ctypes.PyDLL` (`ctypes.pydll.LoadLibrary`)
- Since you're returning a `PyObject*`, on *Python* side you should use *py_object* (check [[SO]: How to cast a ctypes pointer to an instance of a Python class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52053434/how-to-cast-a-ctypes-pointer-to-an-instance-of-a-python-class) for more details)

So, assuming that you have a working *.dll*, here's how would you use it (posting the code blindly):

```py
mylib = ctypes.pydll.LoadLibrary('./mylib.so')
outvar = ctypes.py_object.in_dll(mylib, "outvar")  # Note that you might have to declare it as extern "C", so its name doesn't get mangled
```

***@EDIT0***:

I created a dummy example to test whether everything works.

*dll.c*:

```c
#include <Python.h>

#if defined(_WIN32)
#  define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define EXPORT
#endif


EXPORT PyObject *tp = NULL;
EXPORT int i = 123;
EXPORT char *s = "Gainarie";
EXPORT float f = -3.14;


EXPORT void initTpl() {
    tp = PyTuple_New(2);
    PyTuple_SET_ITEM(tp, 0, PyLong_FromLong(7));
    PyTuple_SET_ITEM(tp, 1, PyLong_FromLong(-9));
}
```

*code.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import ctypes


def main():
    dll = ctypes.PyDLL("./dll.so")
    i = ctypes.c_int.in_dll(dll, "i")
    s = ctypes.c_char_p.in_dll(dll, "s")
    f = ctypes.c_float.in_dll(dll, "f")
    dll.initTpl()
    tp = ctypes.py_object.in_dll(dll, "tp")

    print(i.value, s.value, f.value, tp.value, type(tp.value))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Notes**:

- I only tested on *Win*, as I didn't transfer my files on my *Lnx* *VM*, but this shouldn't be a problem
- Since it's for demo purposes only, I didn't care about *memory leaks* (nor did I check whether *Py_XDECREF* is necessary)

**Output**:

> ```py
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054429301>dir /b
> code.py
> dll.c
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054429301>"c:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2015\vc\vcvarsall.bat" x64
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054429301>cl /nologo /DDLL /MD /I"c:\Install\x64\Python\Python\03.06.08\include" dll.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /LIBPATH:"c:\Install\x64\Python\Python\03.06.08\libs" /OUT:dll.so
> dll.c
>    Creating library dll.lib and object dll.exp
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054429301>dir /b
> code.py
> dll.c
> dll.exp
> dll.lib
> dll.obj
> dll.so
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054429301>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.06.08_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> 123 b'Gainarie' -3.140000104904175 (7, -9) <class 'tuple'>
> ```

Comment: problem is that (a) there's no complex ctype (b) there's no vector c_type (c) I can't use pointer since the size of each list is unknonwn

Comment: I don't understand. It should make no difference, as everything you mentioned is enclosed and internal in the *.dll*, and on *Python* side, you simply don't care, because all you get are *Python* compatible objects, which based on your code snippets seems to be a list of lists of floats.

Comment: So how do i define the ctype variable in Python? how should the python file look? 'myvar = ctype.???.in_dl(dll,'????')'

Comment: What do you mean by ctype? It should only be a ***ctypes*** type, basically a *C* wrapper type. No *C++*.  In my example I exposed such types.

Comment: well, I return an PyObject that is tuple of list of list of complex, how can I get it in Python (what do I need to do to convert the pointer to this object?)

Comment: The conversion is already done by *PyComplex\_FromDoubles*, so you get instances of *Python*'s *complex* class. But all these questions point to the fact that you don't have a working *.dll* yet, otherwise a simple test would have provided all the answers. Is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

I understand from your example that you want to call a C++ function from Python which takes a list of complex numbers and return them.

If you use [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/master/include/pybind11/complex.h) you get the conversion from std::vector and std::complex for free. pybind11 is a header only library.

Here is an example

example.cpp

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/complex.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

std::complex<double> foo(std::complex<double> a)
{
    return a;
}

std::vector<std::complex<double>> foo2(std::vector<std::complex<double>>& v)
{
    return v;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(samplepy, m) {  
    m.def("foo", &foo, "Return the complex number entered as an argument");
    m.def("foo2", &foo2, "Return the list of complex number entered as an argument");
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.13)
project (samplepy CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
file (GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES "*.cpp" "*.h")

if (WIN32)
    find_package(PythonInterp)
    find_package(PythonLibs 3.6 REQUIRED)
    set(PYBIND11_CPP_STANDARD /std:c++latest)
else()
    find_package(PythonLibs 3.6 REQUIRED)
    set(PYBIND11_CPP_STANDARD -std=c++1z)
endif()

add_library (samplepy SHARED ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(samplepy PRIVATE ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
set_target_properties(samplepy PROPERTIES PREFIX "${PYTHON_MODULE_PREFIX}" SUFFIX "${PYTHON_MODULE_EXTENSION}")

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

example.py

```
import samplepy
z = complex(2, -3)
print(type(samplepy.foo(z)))
print(samplepy.foo(z))

l = [complex(1, -2), complex(3, -4)]
print(type(samplepy.foo2(l)))
print(samplepy.foo2(l))
```

When I run this I get this on the py console

```
<class 'complex'>
(2-3j)
<class 'list'>
[(1-2j), (3-4j)]
```

Comment: after compiling, I get an error in python saying it cant find samplepy, did you put it right next to the .py file?

Comment: I added the path where the shared lib file sample.py.so/dll is to the pythonpath environment variable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917492/how-to-use-pythonpath. I hope this helps. Please mark my answer as correct

Comment: Can you elaborate abit more?
I've tried to add os.path.join(os.path.dirname(\__file\__)) at the start of the file but it didn't work, neither adding it to PYTHONPATH

Comment: In a command prompt before running python.exe you need to run this command: `set PYTHONPATH=c:\dev\example\build\debug\bin;%PYTHONPATH%` in the bin folder should contain the samplepy.pyd file you just build for this to work.