# How to fix "Access Violation" error when returning PyObject from C function using PyTCC library

Tags: python, ctypes, jit, tcc

I am using a Python library that wraps LibTCC called [PyTCC](https://github.com/frxstrem/pytcc).

I am experimenting with ways to JIT compile code in Python. Problem is, when calling a function I can return normal C data types correctly but I get an "Access Violation" error when returning any `PyObject *`.

I have made sure that code can execute from PyTCC as my code example shows.  This also means that the code example is compiling successfully.

```py
import ctypes, pytcc

program = b"""
#include "Python.h"

/* Cannot return 3 due to access violation */
PyObject * pop(PyObject * self, PyObject * args, PyObject * kwargs) {
    // Cannot return *any* Python object
    return PyLong_FromLong(3);
}

int foobar() { return 3; }  // Returns 3 just fine

// Needed to appease TCC:
int main() { }
"""

jit_code = pytcc.TCCState()
jit_code.add_include_path('C:/Python37/include')
jit_code.add_library_path('C:/Python37')
jit_code.add_library('python37')
jit_code.compile_string(program)
jit_code.relocate()

foobar_proto = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int)
foobar = foobar_proto(jit_code.get_symbol('foobar'))

print(f'It works: {foobar()}')

pop_proto = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_voidp)
pop = pop_proto(jit_code.get_symbol('pop'))

print('But this does not for some reason:')
print(pop())
print('Never gets here due to access violation :(')
```

The output of the program should be:

```
It works: 3
But this does not for some reason:
3
Never gets here due to access violation :(
```

But instead, I am getting this exact error:

```
It works: 3
But this does not for some reason:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fails.py", line 40, in <module>
    print(pop())
OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x00000000FFC000E9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it's because you don't have the GIL when creating the object.  You also have an issue with the return type. ctypes.c_voidp tells python to treat it like an int instead of a PyObject, so all you'd see if it wasn't for the access violation is the value pointer itself not what it's pointing at.

Try:

```
    PyObject * pop() {
    PyGILState_STATE gstate;
    gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();
    PyObject* obj = PyLong_FromLong(10);
    PyGILState_Release(gstate);
    return obj;
}
```

and switch
`pop_proto = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_voidp)`
to
`pop_proto = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.py_object)`

output from my run (changed the value from 3 to 10 in the pyobject just to show it made it)

```
It works: 3
But this does not for some reason:
10
Never gets here due to access violation :(
```

Comment: Another possibilty would be to use `pop_proto = cytpes.PYFUNCTYPE(ctypes.py_object)`  since that should indicate to not release the GIL to begin with instead of its normal behavior. *Note* I didn't test that.

Comment: Thank you for reply!
I have made those changes and am getting the same error.
I have also tried the proto with: `pop_proto = ctypes.PYFUNCTYPE(ctypes.py_object)` and also `pop_proto = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.py_object)` to no avail.  In addition, I also copy-and-pasted your GIL code example and it did not work. Since you have successfully compiled and run, what platforms (OS/Python) did you test this on?

Comment: debian linux (sid), python 3.6, pytcc that you linked, using tcc version 0.9.27-8 (had to manually compile it for the shared library since debian used the static version in it's package).  It had a few patches from baseline -- `turn off stack-protector in runtime`, `dead code removal on case statements x86 specific`, and `adding pthread library name for linux threaded builds`, and the only changes I made to your python script were the ones posted and the making the load paths work for linux `jit_code.add_include_path('/usr/include/python3.6m') ... `

Comment: I'm banging my head against the wall on this one.  After only making the changes you suggested, I am still getting the error.
Do you happen to have access to a Windows computer that you could test?

Comment: I don't unfortunately.  I wonder if it is the stack protector patch on mine that is allowing it to work.   Can you recompile your tcc and add -fno-stack-protector to the CFLAGS (or whatever the equivalent for the windows compiler) ?

Comment: Just tried that. I recompiled from source and confirmed that the `GS-` [flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gs-buffer-security-check?view=vs-2019) was passed to disable the buffer security check. Unfortunately, I got the same error. I'm using PyTCC because I don't know of another library that can compile C code on the fly from Python. Is there another option I could try that you know of?

Comment: Would something like [numba](http://numba.pydata.org) do what you want?  It jits python code instead of inlining C code

Comment: That's a great idea but I specifically need to compile C code dynamically and quickly (which would make LibTCC a perfect candidate).

Comment: I wonder if it's an OS config thing - try turning off the data execution protection and run it that way. https://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-xp/disable-turn-off-dep-windows/ (has instructions for newer versions of windows as well)

Comment: Ok. I tried looking into DEP and it is already disabled for all but Windows-specific executables.  I have some additional info on the problem though: this function:

```
char duh() {
    malloc(sizeof(int));
    return 'c';
}
```

Will execute just fine without the call to `malloc` and will return the 'c'.  However, when the `malloc` is added, it causes the access violation.
So what I have determined is that the C code cannot allocate memory.
This seems like it has something to do with DEP and non-executable memory pages but I'm not experienced enough to go and actually view it.

Comment: From the Application Compatability section of [ms dep info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/memory/data-execution-prevention) it looks like IMAGE_SCN_MEM_EXECUTE needs to be set for the code to be able to execute.  tcc defines it but doesn't seem to use it, so it's probably not something pytcc can set without modifying it. You might have to disable DEP altogether if you don't want to modify tcc and pytcc since it seems to be affecting things its not turned on explicitly for, though that puts your machine at extra risk.  It would be an interesting test (imho).

Comment: Thank you for the info :).  However, I have found another solution to the issue.
I found another library of the same name: [PyTCC](https://github.com/thgcode/pytcc) that initially gave me the *exact* same error.  I opened an issue on the repo and [thgcode](https://github.com/thgcode) got back to me the same day with a fix. I have gotten the same example using the new API and your changes to work successfully!
Thank you very much for your time and I highly recommend taking a look at [PyTCC](https://github.com/thgcode/pytcc).

Answer (score 0):

Didn't work with *PyTCC*, but there's something wrong in the code.

According to [[Python 3]: *class* ctypes.**PyDLL**(*name, mode=DEFAULT_MODE, handle=None*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.PyDLL) (**emphasis** is mine):

> Instances of this class behave like [CDLL](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.CDLL) instances, except that the Python GIL is *not* released during the function call, and after the function execution the Python error flag is checked. If the error flag is set, a Python exception is raised.
>
> **Thus, this is only useful to call Python C api functions directly**.

**Note**: *CFUNCTYPE* is for *CDLL*, same thing that ***PYFUNCTYPE*** is for ***PyDLL***.

As a consequence, in *pop_proto*, you should replace `ctypes.CFUNCTYPE` with `ctypes.PyFUNCTYPE` (note that you have a typo in ***c_voidp***).

Next, same page states that for *PyObject** (*C*), *py_object* should be used (*Python*). So:

```
pop_proto = ctypes.PyFUNCTYPE(ctypes.py_object)
```

If you want to be rigorous, you'll have to include the arguments in the prototype, which would make the code look a bit more complicated, but for this particular case (they are ignored), it's not mandatory:

```
pop_proto = ctypes.PyFUNCTYPE(ctypes.py_object, ctypes.py_object, ctypes.py_object, ctypes.py_object)
```

Here's an example for `PyObject *PyBytes_Repr(PyObject *obj, int smartquotes)` (calling the *C* function in the "old fashioned" way):

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:C:\WINDOWS\system32]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe"
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> >>>
> >>> import sys
> >>> import os
> >>> import ctypes
> >>>
> >>> python_dll_name = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable), "python" + str(sys.version_info.major) + str(sys.version_info.minor) + ".dll")
> >>> python_dll_name
> 'e:\\Work\\Dev\\VEnvs\\py_064_03.07.03_test0\\Scripts\\python37.dll'
> >>>
> >>> python_dll = ctypes.PyDLL(python_dll_name)
> >>>
> >>> pybytes_repr_proto = ctypes.PYFUNCTYPE(ctypes.py_object, ctypes.py_object, ctypes.c_int)
> >>> pybytes_repr = pybytes_repr_proto(("PyBytes_Repr", python_dll))
> >>>
> >>> b = b"abcd"
> >>>
> >>> reprb = pybytes_repr(b, 0)
> >>> reprb
> "b'abcd'"
> ```

You might also check [[SO]: How to cast a ctypes pointer to an instance of a Python class (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52053434/how-to-cast-a-ctypes-pointer-to-an-instance-of-a-python-class/52055019#52055019).

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have implemented your recommendations and unfortunately it is still throwing an access violation error. I'm just confused because I can return data from a normal C function but not a CPython function, even when manipulating the GIL.

Comment: With the current changes (actually only *py\_object* is required), it works when building the *C* code in  separate *.dll* (original code **doesn't crash**). But for rigorousity's sake it's best to also keep *PYFUNCTYPE*. It seems that *libtcc* adds some extra stuff into play.